# kubuntu samsung uld driver does not print correctly on samsung clp 320 printer: white page with text "spl-c error please use proper driver ..."

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, printing, samsung

I just installed kubuntu 19.04 on my 32-Bit laptop (Samsung R540).

Now I wanted to setup the printer, a Samsung CLP-320 color laser printer which is connected to my router (ethernet cable) - the laptop is connected to the router using the wifi interface.

In the browser, I can access the printer's web-interface 
http://sec001599706e10/sws/index.html
(to check, if the tcp-connection to printer works)

After that, I have run the script install.sh from the unpacked SamsungPrinterInstaller.tar.gz downloaded from here:
http://www.samsungsetup.com/TS/Files/RDS_XML/web_install_agent/linux/SamsungPrinterInstaller.tar.gz

The script ran without any errors. The printer is also shown in kubuntu's printer settings. In kubuntu's printer settings, I can see, that the printer is found: it shows the printers consumables correctly, e.g. that the cyan color is low as is also shown in the printers web-interface...

Everything seems to be fine so far...

But now, when I try to print something, the printer just prints a nearly empty white page with the following text:

```
SPL-C ERROR - Please use the proper driver
    POSITION: 0x0 (0)
    SYSTEM: src_5.47/xl_image
    LINE: 629
    VERSION: SPL-C 5.47 01-15-2010
```

Printing a test page from kubuntu printer settings has the same effect.

I have also tried to delete the printer in kubuntu printer settings and added it in the browser with the cups admin page:
http://localhost:631/admin
(which I read about somewhere else in the internet)
==> no difference

Interestingly the same driver works nicely on my other laptop, a 64-bit-machine (Acer aspire es1-731g-p1mc), same operating system and doing the same steps described above... 
Additionaly, I installed a virtualbox with windows7 as a guest system on the same samsung laptop (which prints the white page) and installed the printer drivers there... printing nicely...

Can anybody help me to get the printer driver running on kubuntu linux 19.04?

Comment: can really nobody answer this question? If you cannot answer, can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah!

I just managed to fix this old problem:

In cups web-interface, I just set the driver of the printer to
'Samsung CLP-325 Foomatic/foo2qpdl (recommended)'

[cups web-interface screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3CjH.png)

And this made it work...

Interestingly, the printer really *is* a CLP-320 printer and *there is* a CLP-320 driver (the driver in the screenshot 'Samsung CLP 320 Series (en)' which does not work).
Anyway, it seems, that printing only works with CLP-325 driver on the ubuntu 32-bit operating system.

I just wonder, why the printer comments the proper (CLP-320) driver with 'spl-c error please use the proper driver' and prints nicely with the not proper (CLP-325) driver ;-)

Is it possible, that CLP-320N (there is no driver for the N modell) is the same as CLP-325 ???

But why does it work with that driver on 64bit, then?